# Python multiprocessing cannot access variable defined in if __name__ == "main"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use windows. I don't understand why the following code fails.

`a`, when defined in the "if main" block, should be a global variable. But running the script I got error "a is not defined". However, if `a` is defined outside the "if main" block, the code will work.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

# a = np.array([1,2,3])
def f(x):
    return a*x

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    a = np.array([1,2,3])
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Only the main thread has `__name__=='__main__'`. The other child threads import your code from a spawned process without setting `__name__` to `__main__`. This is intentional, and required in windows (where [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) is not available), to provide a mechanism for executing code like initializing the pool only in the parent. See discussion here: [Workaround for using __name__=='__main__' in Python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110287/workaround-for-using-name-main-in-python-multiprocessing)